# How to hide grub menu on boot and show it only when pressing a certain key?

Tags: grub

I want to install linux in a machine, along with windows, but I wouldn't want people to notice.

So I thought if there was some way to hide grub menu on startup to make it directly boot from the windows partition, but when a certain key is pressed on startup (let's say left shift, for example) I want the grub menu to appear

Is it possible to do it? Can anybody think about another alternative?

Comment: There are several good answers that show up for a search for [hide grub menu unless key is pressed](https://www.google.com/search?q=hide%20grub%20menu%20unless%20key%20is%20pressed).  Did *your research* miss those?  Did something not work about those?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is a problem with ubuntu's /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober file

I could hide the grub menu by disabling it with

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

but then I lost the other boot options.

I could solve it thanks to this answer at askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/552431/26067

There's a bug in os-prober that overrides the GRUB_TIMEOUT variable, resetting it to 10 seconds.

Some made these workarounds [gists](https://gist.github.com/LeahCim/9332432), they are a couple of scripts that saves the value of timeout and timeout_style variable, and later they restore.

this is how my /etc/default/grub file looks like:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Now I can get to the menu pressing esc when the machine is about to boot.